# Can the boolean difference of boolean function be 0?

Tags: boolean-algebra, differential

Suppose we have a boolean function $$f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$$ 
The boolean differential of this function is defined as follows 
$$
\frac{df(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)}{dx_i} = 
f\big|_{x_i = 0 } \oplus f\big|_{x_i = 1 } = \\
f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_{i-1}, 0, x_{i+1}, ..., x_n) \ \oplus \
f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, ..., x_n)
$$ 
Can this differential be equal to 0 and what does it mean when it is?

Comment: What does $\oplus$ mean?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It is the "exclusive or" which is, for instance, used in Zhegalkin polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if $X$ and $Y$ are truth values, then $X \oplus Y = 0$ means that $X$ and $Y$ are the same (check the truth table, if you didn't know that). Can you now see the answer?

> The boolean differential $df/dx_{i}$ is (the constant function) $0$ iff the value of $f$ is independent of $x_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am now embarrassed that I have asked this question.

Comment: Don't worry: we all have blank page syndrome from time to time.